# Any recent performance comparison among Javascript, Silverlight and Flash

Tags: javascript, silverlight, flash, comparison, benchmarking

This is really a duplicate of the question-
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322183/does-silverlight-have-a-performance-advantage-over-javascript)

I googled it and found some old results like bubblemark.com, [link text](http://www.timo-ernst.net/riabench-start/) and [link text](http://www.3djam.com/roozz/demo/speed_demo.aspx). But is there any recent benchmarks as all the platforms have been updated. I like to measure the speed of silverlight 4 against the modern and faster javascript engines. Anyone have any source?

Comment: I'm betting the Javascript numbers have gone way up in recent years. It's probably your best bet for those reasons alone: it's deployed almost everywhere, and most rapidly improving.

Comment: Javascript is far behind in terms of performance thats for sure. However new browsers such as IE9 and Firefox 4 support DirectDraw rendering, this could dramatically increase performance in some scenarios because the load is taken from teh CPU to the GPU. Javascript would still be behind in terms of purely computational performance however

Comment: Your choice of language to use, on any specific given browser-based project, is unlikely to come down to computational speed alone. Personally we use JS for legacy stuff only now and Silverlight/ASP hybrid projects for anything new as all the so-called problems with Silverlight are either now fixed (mouse, printing, files etc) or have work-arounds (SEO via parallel ASP.Net).

Comment: @HiTechMagic I agree that Sivlerlight 5 has solved a lot of the issues, but considering it looks like Microsoft will not support Silverlight any more, I'm not sure if it's future proof.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found too much for new raw JavaScript engine numbers or for Silverlight, but along those lines are some benchmarks of HTML5 verse Flash if that helps you at all. Of course it takes into account rendering performance rather than just pure computational performance:

http://themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2010/03/22/

there is also a video showing the tests being performed on mobile devices http://vimeo.com/10553088

Certainly JavaScript engines have made up a lot of ground. Google's V8 engine added a JIT compiler which was much needed and helps reduce the performance hit of being dynamically typed.

While I don't have sources atm to back this up I suspect that for raw speed it is Silverlight > Flash > JavaScript. Of course in applications the biggest bottlneck is the rendering which is why IE9's GPU rendering has seen some massive speed increases in some tests. This can also be seen in Flash with Joa Ebert's Java+OpenGL implementation of the Flash Player showing big increases in some areas. http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2010/08/19/introducing-jitb/